# How do I log multiple %m messages using log4j

Tags: java, log4j

I am trying to use a console logger to produce this style of log message:

`System.out.printf("%-42s [%s]\n", "Ping SLAVE on " + localTarget.getHostName() + "...", slaveAgent.ping());`

On the console that would look like:

`Ping SLAVE on ovm1...                      [OK]`

Is is possible to format the output like this with log4j? So far I have this in the log4j.xml:

`<appender name="serviceConsole" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern"
                value="%-42m [%m]%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>`

I think this will probably put the %m (Ping SLAVE on ovm1...) into both parts of the output. I am not sure how to pass the second part. I have this in the log line:

`SLOGGER.info("Ping SLAVE on " + localTarget.getHostName() + "..." + slaveAgent.ping());`

Comment: Why not format the string in java and send the formatted message to log4j?  
`String msg = String.format("%-42s [%s]\n", "Ping SLAVE on " + localTarget.getHostName() + "...", slaveAgent.ping());  
SLOGGER.info(msg);`

Comment: I suppose I can do that - I can just create a method to pad before sending to log4j.